# How to fix Jquery focus issue using with AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a directive `character-counter` for character counter when user enter text into `textarea` its working as expected but i am having one issue here when user finish typing in `textarea` i have to click on save to post the data but because of `focusOut` i have to click twice on save button so on first click it focus out the counter and second click i am able to save the data.

Is there any other solution that can take care of this problem that i can use for this directive ?

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea rows="8" class="textAreaModal" ng-model="ratingQstnResult.rationaleSelect[ratingQstnResult.rationaleSelectedKey]" maxlength="4000" character-counter></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="rationaleWin.close();">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ratingQstnResult.rationaleSelect[ratingQstnResult.rationaleSelectedKey]=null; rationaleWin.close();">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('riskAssessmentApp').directive('characterCounter', function () {
  'use strict';
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngmodel) {
            var characterCount;
            element.after('<p class="character-count" style="display: none;"><span class="characters-left"></span> characters left</p>');
            element.focus(function(){
                element.next().show();
            });
            element.focusout(function(){
                element.next().hide();
            });
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return ngmodel.$viewValue;
            }, function(newVal){
                if(newVal){
                    characterCount = parseInt(attrs.maxlength - newVal.length, 10);

                } else{
                    characterCount = parseInt(attrs.maxlength, 10);
                }
                element.next().find('.characters-left').text(characterCount);

            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't return the event from the focusout() method and the event is not propagating. Try this:

```
element.focusout(function(event){
                element.next().hide();
                return event;
            });
```